# Why Pandas insists on writing to a already filled line in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

This is my CSV file:

```
name;sex;email
paul;male;paul@gmail.com
```

Then I'm trying to add these two users to the CSV:

```
import pandas

users = [
    {'name': "john", 'sex' : 'male', 'email' : 'john@gmail.com'},
    {'name': "yoko", 'sex' : 'female', 'email' : 'yoko@gmail.com'}
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(users)
df.to_csv('users.csv', sep=';', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
```

But Pandas insists on writing John's information on Paul's line:

```
name;sex;email
paul;male;paul@gmail.comjohn;male;john@gmail.com
yoko;female;yoko@gmail.com
```

Why's that? How can we give John his own line?? Please help us!!

Comment: Looks like your original CSV is missing the trailing `\n` at the end of the last line.

Comment: Why are you using pandas?

Comment: Pandas is mandatory, I have a huge database. I know a "\n" would solve the problem, but I'm afraid some dev fellow would just drop the blank line. I wonder if there isn't a more elegant solution...

Comment: Did you try to read the file into a DataFrame then add the new rows then write back out to the file?

Comment: Looks like you would have to subclass a Pandas class, DataFrame or DataFrameRenderer or CSVFormatter and roll your own. Or Make an io.StringIO object with a newline character and pass it to to_csv then write that to the file. If you add comments to your code with warnings about dropping the newline addition and a *fellow dev* still doesn't heed the warning then your cause is lost.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the file you are appending to doesn't end in a newline - and pandas doesnt't insert a newline before starting to write.

You could probably do something like this before you do df.to_csv(...):

```py
with open('users.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Yes! That's the trick I'm using now... But I wonder if there isn't a more elegant solution, using only Pandas.